# How to trigger $destroy event of already removed element scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Consider the following directive:

```
class HasPermissionDirective {
    constructor(PermissionService) {
        this.restrict = 'A';
        this.priority = 1005;

        this.PermissionService = PermissionService;
    }

    compile(element, attrs) {
        let permission = _.trim(attrs.hasPermission),
            hide       = _.get(attrs, 'hideOnly'),
            $element   = angular.element(element);

        if (permission && !this.PermissionService.hasPermission(permission)) {
            if (!_.isUndefined(hide)) {
                hide = _.trim(hide);

                if (hide === 'visibility') {
                    $element.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                } else {
                    $element.hide();
                }
            } else {
                $element.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    link($scope, $element, attrs, ctrl) {
        $scope.$destroy();
    }
}

HasPermissionDirective.$inject = ['PermissionService'];
```

The problem is now, the $scope.$destroy() is executed always, for every element-scope the directive is attached to (of course).

When I'm now add a "isRemoved" member variable and set it to true in case the element was removed and do the following in the link function:

```
if (this.isRemoved) {
    $scope.$destroy();
}
```

Of course the $scope.$destroy() is triggered for every element-scope as soon as at least one element is removed, cause the directive is handled as a singleton not as an instance.

I cannot add any information to the element node since it seems to be removed after compile and is only a comment node "ngInclude: undefined" (no, I don't remove the node, I add an data-attribute and want to get it inside of the link function: `$element.data('remove', true)` and then want to $destroy and remove()). EDIT: This seems to be the transclude-behavior of the ngInclude-directive.

If I remove the $scope.$destroy() from the link-function and just remove the node, the ngInclude-directive is still running ...

Waht I want? I just want to remove the element from DOM while compile time since the current user has not the permission to see this element/directive/view and I also want to avoid further processing of directives (in my case the ng-include which should not unnecessary request templates (since our server will respond 401 anyway) and so on).

UPDATE: I guess i need a way to set the `terminal` option inside of the compile function to stop the processing of the upcoming directives. My problem is that ngInclude is running even though the element was removed before.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found! I also have to to use transclusion (it was clear after I was checking the impl of ngIf) and its only possible inside of (pre/post)link function(s), so here the impl. for someone who runs into similar problems:

```
class HasPermissionDirective {
    constructor(PermissionService) {
        this.restrict = 'A';
        this.priority = 1011; // high prio so the element is removed before all other directives can be processed
        this.transclude = 'element';
        this.$$tlb = true; // BAD! But w/o, transclusion for different directives won't work :(

        this.PermissionService = PermissionService;
    }

    preLink($scope, $element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
        let $newScope = $scope.$new(),
            hide = _.get(attrs, 'hideOnly');

        $transclude($newScope, ($clone) => {
            if (!this.PermissionService.hasPermission(_.trim(attrs.hasPermission))) {
                if (!_.isUndefined(hide)) {
                    hide = _.trim(hide);

                    if (hide === 'visibility') {
                        $clone.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    } else {
                        $clone.hide();
                    }
                } else {
                    $newScope.$destroy();
                    $newScope = null;

                    $clone.remove();
                    $clone = null;
                }
            } else {
                // in case the user has the permission we have to attach the element to the DOM (cause of transclusion)
                $element.after($clone);
            }
        });
    }
}

HasPermissionDirective.$inject = ['PermissionService'];
```

I did also outsource the implementation to a controller so I can reuse the logic, but I wan't to provide a complete example for clarification :)